# Trying to understand the differences between basic properties of $\mathbb{L}^2$ norm and the absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$ (if any exist)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that $f,g:A\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is real value function, then it holds that
$$(f(x)+g(x))^2=|f(x)+g(x)|^2\leq(|f(x)|+|g(x)|)^2$$
Also, suppose that $X,Y\in\mathbb{L}^2(\Omega,\mathbb{F}_{s},\mathbb{P})$ and $||\cdot||_{\mathbb{L}^2}:V\subset\mathbb{L}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ stands for the L-square norm and $f,g:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Is the property of the absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfied in the following way in $\mathbb{L}^2$?
$$(f(X,Y)+g(X,Y))^2=||f(X,Y)+g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}^2\leq\left(||f(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}+||g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(f(X,Y) + g(X,Y))^2 = \| f(X,Y) + g(X,Y)\|_{L^2}^2$$
does not make sense because the left-hand side is a function whereas the right-hand side is a number.

On the other hand, the triangle inequality says
$$\|f(X,Y) + g(X,Y)\|_{L^2} \leq \|f(X,Y)\|_{L^2} + \|g(X,Y)\|_{L^2},$$
which, upon squaring, becomes the desired inequality.

Comment: What do you mean by saying ``which, upon squaring, becomes the desired inequality?" Could you provide more details?

Comment: @Nav89  You want $$||f(X,Y)+g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}^2\leq\left(||f(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}+||g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\right)^2.$$
You have
$$||f(X,Y)+g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\leq\left(||f(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}+||g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\right).$$
Square both sides.

Comment: Well, the conection that I want to make is between $(f(X,Y)+g(X,Y))^2$ and $\left(||f(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}+||g(X,Y)||_{\mathbb{L}^2}\right)^2$ if there is any...So, this is why I am writing the equation that you see...

Comment: Is there any case that they are connected somehow?

Comment: Ok i see, there is no connection between them. You can not claim that the left hand side equation holds, since this is a function and the right hand is a number. But I thought threre was some property that connected them to find some upper and lower bounds...